# Angularfire2 redirect after login

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

i'm using ionic 2 rc0 and angular 2 and i just added angularfire2 to use firebse auth.

I have all configured and tested (I just see my user logged in the firebase console) but i want to redirect to other page after login.

My code for login:

```
registerUserWithGoogle() {
   console.log('Google');
   this.af.auth.login();
}
```

My firebase config is:

```
export const myFirebaseAuthConfig = {
   provider: AuthProviders.Google,
   method: AuthMethods.Redirect
};
```

So there is a way to redirect after the method login()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AngularFire2 has a property named `authState` in `AngularFireAuth`, to which you can subscribe to get the auth state changes

This is recommended way to handle user auth, because you will subscribe to changes in the auth state, other methods might not work as expected, like when user refreshes the page user object might not exist.

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        // go to home page
      } else {
        // go to login page
      }
    });
  }

}
```

**Note:** You don't need to subscribe on every page. Only subscribe in `AppComponent` or your app specific root component.

Comment: thank you, it works now i need a logout method cause im still loged but it redirects so ty so much

Comment: just call `this.auth.logout()`, it will log you out and `else` part of `auth.subscribe` will be called

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work better in my situation.

```
loginGoogle(){
  this.af.auth.login({
    provider: AuthProviders.Google
  }).then((success) => {
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  });
}
```

Comment: For some reason the 'then' promise function wasn't being hit for me, so I did the init approach above.

Comment: The then wasn't working for me either. When you make a call to login() it reloads your component after the user has been authenticated and thus that promise never gets fulfilled.

Comment: hello Alex Harper i implementing your code but still is not working. it redirecting with login and signup components in single page.