# Promise Return function not called

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using Ionic2 rc4.  I am trying to using Firebase to Authenticate a user.  I have the following code that works with Firebase, however when it has saved the user to Firebase (`loginGoogle()`), I would expect it to call the `setUpUser` function below, but it doesn't get invoked.

**Question**

How can I get `'LoginPage.loginGoogle()'` invoked after it has authenticated with Firebase.

```
import { FirebaseAuth, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  jobModel: JobModel;
  personModel: PersonModel;

  constructor(private nav: NavController, public auth: FirebaseAuth, public utilityService: UtilityService, public personService: PersonService) {
  }

  setUpUser() {
    alert('setUpUser');
    console.log('LoginPage', window.localStorage.getItem('uid'));
    let promisePersonModel: Promise<PersonModel> = this.personService.getPersonByUid(window.localStorage.getItem('uid'));
    promisePersonModel.then((personModel: PersonModel) => {
      this.personModel = personModel;
      if (!this.personModel) {
        this.personModel = new PersonModel();
        this.personModel.uid = window.localStorage.getItem('uid');
        this.personModel.emailAddress = window.localStorage.getItem('email');
        this.personModel.userName = window.localStorage.getItem('displayName');
        this.personModel.avatar = window.localStorage.getItem('photoURL');
        this.utilityService.login(this.personModel);
        console.log('LoginPage. logged in', this.personModel);
        this.personService.savePerson(this.personModel).then((personModel: PersonModel) => {
          console.log('LoginPage.saved personModel', personModel);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  loginGoogle() {
    this.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Google,
      method: AuthMethods.Redirect
    }).then((Data) => {
      console.log('LoginPage.loginGoogle()', window.localStorage.getItem('uid'), Data);
      this.setUpUser();
      this.nav.setRoot(SearchJobsPage);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Isn't `AuthMethods.Redirect` going to be the culprit? Won't that leave your app? I'd do some searching re: Fireabase + Ionic + `AuthMethods.Redirect`

Comment: are you getting anything in the logs?

Comment: Hi suraj, there is nothing in the logs.

Comment: Hi cartant, yes I think you are right, I think the page is redirecting so it doesn't invoke the lifecycle function.  I will investigate further how to fix this.

Comment: There is a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126710/angularfire2-redirect-after-login). Whether or not redirecting is the best solution, I don't know. There is a Cordova InAppBrowser, but whether it's workable, again, don't know. If you do redirect, you can listen for [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) when you get back and Firebase will log you in. If/when you get it working, please post your own answer.

Comment: Also, I only happened upon your reply by chance. You might want to have a look at how [replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) work.

Comment: I try the following with no success.  `this.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {...` it says `[ts] Property 'onAuthStateChanged' does not exist on type 'FirebaseAuth'.`

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/Auth-with-Ionic2.md#configuring-angularfire2-auth-with-ionic2